# Pulling files from a user's directory with angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular

For a school project classmates and I are putting together a web api that needs to be able to grab photos from the user. Then put these photos into a database.

A problem we have ran into is that we do not have any idea how to pull photos from the users local computer and push them down to our back end operation. From there we can put the photos into the database.

We are using a .net web application and using angular on are front end.

How do we setup an angular controller that grabs a directory (folder) of .jpeg files and pushes it to our MVC controller on the backend?

If we could be pointed to any resources that explain this process, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `<input type="file" name="images" multiple />`.  Do some research starting with that and see if you can learn some techniques.

Comment: For security reasons, the browser simply cannot go digging around the user's disk without the user explicitly directing it every step of the way. You would not want a webpage doing that on your computer. You should do as Squillman suggests, and look into file drag and drop as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, and yeah i figured it was not appropriate to just go through a user's local disk. I figured there would be some sort of permissions involved. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The uses will need to press a button to open file selector. There you can select multiple files. Or you can implement a drag and drop.

Here below is an angular solution to upload to the server

http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/

At the server you will need to implement saving the file.

Comment: Thank you so much. This looks perfect. I appreciate the quick feedback. I will be trying it out, let you know how it goes.